# Send Audio Over Python GATT Server

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, pyaudio, bluetooth-gatt

I am using a python GATT server to send data from a Raspberry Pi to an iPhone application over Bluetooth Low Energy. Currently I am able to send simple sensor data by altering this [github project](https://github.com/Douglas6/cputemp).

Ultimately I would like to send audio captured and filtered in Python over BLE. However, unlike the sensor data, the microphone sample rate needs to be very high (ideally 44.1 kHz). I'm wondering if there is any way to achieve this using the GATT server.

current implementation (called every 1ms using add_timeout) :

```
def get_frame(self):
    print("getting current frame")
    # capture 4096 chunk from pyaudio stream
    data = self.stream.read(self.chunk)
    data =[]
    for x in data:
        print("Appending data")
        value.append(dbus.Byte(x))
    
    print("sending value")
    
    # send frame as byte array over GATT Server
    return value
```

Comment: Some people use BLE for audio streaming, but Bluetooth Classic would be much more suited for this kind of data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Voice capability option in bluetooth low energy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152624/voice-capability-option-in-bluetooth-low-energy)